# xargs grep ignore files that dont meet query

Tags: bash, unix, grep, xargs

Quick question regarding doing a grep with xargs.  When I do it, I will be displayed with a bunch of results from files that dont exist interspersed with files that do successfully match the search criteria, such as:

```
find . | xargs grep 'Cache'

grep: PT: No such file or directory
grep: Sans: No such file or directory
grep: Free: No such file or directory
grep: Font: No such file or directory
grep: License.txt: No such file or directory
```

Is there an arg that can be passed that will only display hits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filenames contain spaces, so you need to tell `find` to output the results separated by NUL bytes rather than newlines - try the following instead:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 egrep 'Cache'
```

The `-0` to `xargs` says to interpret the data from STDIN as
being separated by NUL bytes.  (The single quotes around `Cache` are unnecessary here.)

Many tools on Unix-like systems similarly have an option to produce or consume
data separated by NUL bytes, since `0x00` and `0x2F` (forward slash)
are the only two bytes that aren't allowed in file or directory
names - it's a common way of dealing safely with filenames with spaces
or newlines.

As a final note, to be very picky you might want to change that to:

```
xargs -0 egrep Cache /dev/null
```

... so that you're sure that there will always be more than one parameter to `grep` and you get output that's consistently prefixed with the filename.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `grep`, just make it recursive

```
grep -R "Cache" *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . | xargs grep 'Cache' 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

When using find with xargs you should always use -print0 because The separator problem of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem . However, if you have a list of files that are each on a line you may want to take a look at GNU Parallel:

```
find . | parallel grep Cache
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ